# Put the key generated by aes into a file

Tags: cryptography, aes, public-key-encryption, private-key, encryption-symmetric

I use the following command for aes encryption:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -in inputfile.txt -out ountputfile.enc
```

This works fine, it asks for a passphrase and verifies it and encrypts the file. I want to put the key generated by aes-128-cbc using the pass phrase into a file. 
Can someone please help me what command should I use to such that after entering the passphrase aes generates the key and writes it into a file.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the -p flag and redirect output to a file:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -p -in inputfile.txt -out ountputfile.enc > keyInfo
```

The key is on the second line of the output file.